# Apache Camel for Asynchronous Calls

Tags: java, asynchronous, jms, messaging, apache-camel

Does it make sense to use Apache Camel for Asynchronous requests? Or should I use simple MoM using a JMS server.
There are no Enterprise Integration Patterns that I'll require.

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you are not using any Enterprise Integration Patterns (yet) - Camel is great at integrating messaging into your application while [hiding all of the middleware APIs](http://camel.apache.org/hiding-middleware.html) while letting you easily switch between all the [various different middleware technologies](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) usually by just changing one or two strings.

e.g. see these links for more detail

- [POJO producing](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html)
- [POJO consuming](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-consuming.html)
- [Spring remoting](http://camel.apache.org/spring-remoting.html)

There is a [POJO Messaging Example](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-messaging-example.html) that walks you through using Camel purely as a way to integrate messaging into your POJOs

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense to use Camel for async calls, especially because it can handle callbacks cleanly. For example:

```
template.asyncCallback("activemq:queue:longTasks", request, callback);
```

Where a callback is a org.apache.camel.spi.Synchronization object that handles both responses as well as failure conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers:
Camel also provides many very useful utils for common programming tasks.

I haven't used it in 8 months, but I'll be using it on my next project...sprint 0 next week.

Perhaps, I too will have more questions on the latest of camel soon.

Happy coding.